# Loading Flux and CuArrays in Different Orders Causes Errors

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I'm trying to get Flux and CuArrays to work on my GPU enabled laptop using POP!_OS. I get errors on the second package that I load.

I initially didn't have CUDA tools installed but now that I do I get errors for each package.

My cuda info is:

```
(base) ➜ ~ find / -type d -name cuda 2>/dev/null

/usr/lib/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/cuda
/usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/cuda
/home/kailukowiak/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/cuda
/home/kailukowiak/anaconda3/pkgs/numba-0.43.1-py37h962f231_0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/cuda
/home/kailukowiak/.julia/packages/CUDAnative/gJDZI/src/device/cuda
/home/kailukowiak/.julia/packages/Flux/qXNjB/src/cuda
/home/kailukowiak/.julia/packages/Flux/qXNjB/test/cuda
```

If I run the following code chunks in different Julia sessions

```
using CuArrays
using Flux
```

```
using Flux
using CuArrays
```

I get:

```
┌ Warning: CUDNN is not installed, some functionality will not be available.
└ @ Flux.CUDA ~/.julia/packages/Flux/qXNjB/src/cuda/cuda.jl:35
```

However, the error is associated with different packages depending on the order.

[Errors Depending on Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWgpr.png)

Does anybody have any ideas for what I could try?

Thanks

Comment: This is likely a Requires.jl bug.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I was able to get it working by adding `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/cuda/lib64` to my .bashrc. Although I might make a PR to change the error messages to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after quite a bit of hair pulling, I was able to get it working by adding `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/cuda/lib64` to my `.bashrc` file.

I believe that julia/Flux/CuArrays was just unbale to find the CUDNN Toolkit.